# how to change or hide a imageView size, without scale image?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, mask

I'm making a volume meter, this volume is basically an Image, that as the sound changes, the view of the image increases or decreases. but when only change the frame size image resets to the new frame, when in reality what I want is to keep the image the same size and just show the content that appears on the frame, not stretching my image.

there may be better ways of doing this, using layers,masks or other things like this, I accept suggestions.

thx

Comment: You may want to be more specific, instead of saying "basically an image" you may want to state UIImageView or UIImage, etc. Also, I read this twice and it still is not clear what exactly you are asking. Can you provide examples?

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted. I changed view mode to left and putting the image size properly (before it was bigger than it actually would be used in the application).
Thx for attention, i've tried to do this before but the real image size excede the view frame, bursting size causing bugs.